# ASP.NET MVC - How to use Required message inside a EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have a simple model:

```
    public abstract class Person
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il nome è obbligatorio!!!")]
        [UIHint("txtGeneric")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il cognome è obbligatorio!!!")]
        [UIHint("txtGeneric")]
        [Display(Name = "Cognome")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "L'email è obbligatoria e deve essere in formato valido (nome@dominio.it)!!!")]
        [UIHint("txtEmail")]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I created inside the EditorTemplate the txtGeneric.cshtml file. It is like this:

```
@model string
<input name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="MESSAGE_TO_PUT" value="@Model" />
```

I want to know how to take the text associated Errormessage of Required attribute to put into my txtGeneric.cshtml file.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: There are two ways to set validation . 1. @Html.ValidationSummary() // for complete model 2. @Html.ValidationMessageFor(/*expression*/) // for selected model property.
Seems you are missing validation helper.

Comment: Yes, I know the Validation helper snd I will put sooner, the thing that I wantis a little bit different...I want to get the text value of the message for required that I set into the model inside a custon template (for custom javascript purpose)...is that possible?!?

Comment: You can use jquery and retrieve inner text. 
check rendered html of validation helper and get innertxt of it.

Comment: Mmmm is it no possible to accessto this value directly into the editortemplate?!? I want to populate a property of the template itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
 @{
     string requiredMsg = "";
     foreach (var attr in @Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, @ViewData.ModelMetadata))
     {
         if (attr.Key == "data-val-required") {
             requiredMsg = attr.Value.ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

or this:

```
 @{
     string requiredMsg = "";
     IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> clientRules = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(ViewData.ModelMetadata, ViewContext).SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules());
     foreach (ModelClientValidationRule rule in clientRules)
     {
         if (rule.ValidationType == "required")
         {
             requiredMsg = rule.ErrorMessage;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify your template to this:

```
   @model string
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: In that way the vallidation message should be outside the input field generated by the editortemplate...i want to access just the text and I want to put inside the input result itself

Comment: Read the value of `data-val-required` attribute from genrated input `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Il nome è obbligatorio!!!" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">`

Comment: No I'm sorry, but my english is bad and my explanation also. I want to get the text of the message inside the EditorTemplates something like @ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix but for required message

Comment: @pinguinone If you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` as suggested by Mohsen, the standard editor template will use data annotations to create corresponding data-val attributes. In other words, you do not need to do anything, unless you intend to provide custom data annotations. But that's completely separate problem.